# What does C5002 1204 auto-vectorizer reason code mean?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, x86, visual-studio-2019, auto-vectorization

I'm a student and I'm learning for techniques of vectorization. I'm trying to make compiler vectorize a function which multiplies two matricies (each matrix consists of elements that are matricies of equal size). The code looks as follows:

```
#define f_dim1 2000
#define f_dim2 240
#define s_dim1 240
#define s_dim2 2000

#define i_dim1 4
#define i_dim2 4

void automaticallyBuilt(float* firstMatrix, float* secondMatrix, float* result) {
    for (int i = 0; i < f_dim2; i++) { // rows in frist matrix
        for (int j = 0; j < s_dim1; j++) { // columns in second matrix
            for (int o = 0; o < f_dim1; o++) { // row element of first matrix = column element of second
                for (int k = 0; k < i_dim2; k++) { // rows in inner matrix
                    for (int l = 0; l < i_dim1; l++) { // columns in inner matrix
                        for (int h = 0; h < i_dim2; h++) { // row element of inner = column element of inner
                            *(result + i*s_dim1*i_dim2*i_dim1 + j*i_dim2*i_dim1 + k*i_dim1 + l) +=
                                *(firstMatrix + i*f_dim1*i_dim2*i_dim1 + o*i_dim2*i_dim1 + k*i_dim1 + h) *
                                *(secondMatrix + o*s_dim1*i_dim2*i_dim1 + j*i_dim2*i_dim1 + h*i_dim1 + l);
                            // smth like result[i][j][k][l] += firstMatrix[i][o][k][h] * secondMatrix[o][j][h][l];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In attempt to make compiler vectorize it I modified this code as follows:

```
#define f_dim1 2000
#define f_dim2 240
#define s_dim1 240
#define s_dim2 2000

#define i_dim1 4
#define i_dim2 4

void automaticallyVectorized(float* firstMatrix, float*  secondMatrix, float* result) {
    for (int i = 0; i < f_dim2; i++) { // rows in frist matrix
        for (int o = 0; o < f_dim1; o++) { // row element of first matrix = column element of second
            for (int j = 0; j < s_dim1; j++) { // columns in second matrix
                for (int k = 0; k < i_dim2; k++) { // rows in inner matrix
                    for (int h = 0; h < i_dim2; h++) { // row element of inner = column element of inner
                        float firstMatrixInnerRowElement = *(firstMatrix + i*f_dim1*i_dim2*i_dim1 + o* i_dim2*i_dim1 + k*i_dim1 + h);
                        float* resultInnerRow = result + i*s_dim1*i_dim2*i_dim1 + j*i_dim2*i_dim1 + k*i_dim1;
                        float* secondMatrixInnerColumnElementRow = secondMatrix + o*s_dim1*i_dim2*i_dim1 + j*i_dim2*i_dim1 + h*i_dim1;
                        for (int l = 0; l < i_dim1; l++) { // columns in inner matrix
                            resultInnerRow[l] += firstMatrixInnerRowElement * secondMatrixInnerColumnElementRow[l];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

During build compiler emits the following message:

> code.cpp(161) : info C5002: Loop not vectorized due to reason: "1204"

Code 1204 is not mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/vectorizer-and-parallelizer-messages?view=msvc-160#BKMK_ReasonCode120x). Furthermore, I haven't found any information about it with Google.
I tried to use `__restrict` modifier but had no luck.

I use Visual Studio 2019, but I tried to build it with VS 2017 with the same results.

Can anybody explain what this reason code means? I don't believe that nobody faced this issue before.

Comment: At the bottom of the Microsoft documentation page you linked, click on the Feedback for **This page** and tell them about the omission for `1204`.

Comment: @Eljay thanks for suggestion! I will post a link to the github issue here as soon as they answer

Comment: Do GCC or clang vectorize it?  Their warning messages (https://llvm.org/docs/Vectorizers.html#diagnostics) might be more descriptive, and and least are intended to be self-contained, never using a numeric code that you're supposed to look up elsewhere.  (https://godbolt.org/z/4arMq5 shows clang *does* vectorize with `__restrict` on all 3 pointers, but it doesn't for your source as-is, saying that "runtime pointer checks needed".  Apparently it chooses not to generate asm that checks for overlap or not, and select between 2 version of the loop.  GCC and clang sometimes do that.)

Comment: @PeterCordes thank you for comment! I find that https://godbolt.org is really interesting and useful tool. I will think about starting using other compiler than MSVC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This reason code means that loops are nested too deeply

As Eljay suggested, I posted an issue on github using the link at the bottom of the documentation page. Here is the [link](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/cpp-docs/issues/2467) to the answer.

Comment: I am glad you have got your solution and thanks for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.